# How to test nginx config file in laravel or php?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a task in Laravel to create a nginx.conf file in storage folder and test the file with nginx command. I have created a config file 'nginx.conf' in storage folder and I tried to test with the help of nginx command, shell_exec() or exec() but I am getting error 'Permission denied'.

Here is the command line I have followed to test nginx.conf file https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/#

**NginxController.php**

```
public function nginxConfig(){
        $path              = storage_path('app/nginx/nginx.conf'); //"/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/app/nginx.conf"
        /*$change_mode       = exec('chmod -R 755 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/app/nginx 2>&1');*/
        $config            = exec('/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/app/nginx -t 2>&1');
        dd($config);
        /*$restart_config    = shell_exec('/etc/init.d/nginx restart');
        $reload            = shell_exec('nginx -s reload');*/
    }
```

**message getting**

```
"sh: 1: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/app/nginx: Permission denied"
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2

root /var/www/google.de/beta.google.de
index index.html index.htm index.php

server_name beta.google.de

include var/www/includes/contao
include var/www/includes/shopware

location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
         access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do it without `sudo` so what you can try is to install [OpenSSH Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) and [Laravel's Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/envoy) add your private ssh key to root's authorized keys and then try to write this in **Envoy** with root access. The `Envoy.blade.php` will look like:

```
@servers(['nginx' => isset($server) ? $server : 'root@localhost'])

@task('testconf', ['on' => 'nginx'])
    {-- here you do what you whant to check --}
@endtask
```

Then in PHP you just addinf `shell` execution of the envoy command like:

```
envoy run testconf
```